# else block in if statement is never reached

Tags: javascript

I know there are many similar questions on IF statements, but I haven't found one specific to my case

I can't see why the else block is never hit when the condition should be toggling between true and false

```js
document.getElementById("outlineCheck").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    if (document.getElementById("outlineCheck").checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("outlineCheck").checked = false;
    } else {
      console.log("hit")
      document.getElementById("outlineCheck").checked = true;
    }
  });
```

```html
<label><input asp-for="CourseOfferingOverviewFlag" value="1" 
     id="outlineCheck" type="radio" />
```

Comment: In your actual code do you set the handler before it’s rendered?

Comment: You have true hard-coded into the element (value=1), so it will always equate to true. Perhaps try removing that?

Comment: @user6854465 He never uses the value, what does that have to do with it?

Comment: If you want something that toggles between two states, use a checkbox, not a radio button. You don't need JavaScript to make it toggle, that's what it does by default.

Comment: He seems to be checking for 'truthyness', which will lead to the first block of the if. The 'truthyness' seems to be being set with the value attribute

Comment: @user6854465 He's checking the truthiness of the `checked` property, not the value.

Comment: `checked` is true if the button is checked, `false` if the button is not checked. The value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never gets to the `else` because you always undo what the user did.

The button is initially unchecked. When the user clicks on the button, it gets checked, so you go into the `if` block and uncheck the button. The next time the user clicks on the button, the same thing happens.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using a checkbox instead as it allowed me to do what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar answer you are unchecking the checkbox all the time.
If you are trying to do something in checked or unchecked mode,
I think you can do like this to have access to both conditions:

P.S. Try to cache your DOM access for better performance.

Example

```js
var $checkbox = document.getElementById("outlineCheck");

$checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if ($checkbox.checked) {
    console.log('Now is checked')
  } else {
    console.log('And now is unchecked')
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="outlineCheck">TEST
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're recommending he cache his DOM to increase performance yet you're importing jQuery for no clear reason?

Comment: @LukeSalamone lol it was in my previous example, of course I would not let that on purpose...

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use radio input you should have at least two inputs radio, for this reason, the first click will be true and not able to make it false, you should use checkbox instead. [more info](https://www.elated.com/html-checkboxes-radio-buttons-select-form-fields/)